# .net WFC json response to return non json formatted data

Tags: .net, sql-server, json, vb.net, wcf

I have a system that is currently returning json data and i have had a request to return non formatted json data.

The current response is

> {"GetBlendResult":[{"age":"0","dateofsomething":"23/09/1951 12:00:00
>   AM","firstname":"Henry James","otherdatedate":"24/09/1951 12:00:00
>   AM","location":"In and
>   around","surname":"Brown","type":"Blue"},{"age":"64","dateofsomething":"18/05/1950
>   12:00:00 AM","firstname":"Herbert James","otherdatedate":"20/05/1950
>   12:00:00 AM","location":"Building
>   J","surname":"Brown","type":"Green"}]}

However the client wants as above but encased in some text

> jsoncallback({"GetBlendResult":[{"age":"0","dateofsomething":"23/09/1951
>   12:00:00 AM","firstname":"Henry James","otherdatedate":"24/09/1951
>   12:00:00 AM","location":"In and
>   around","surname":"Brown","type":"Blue"},{"age":"64","dateofsomething":"18/05/1950
>   12:00:00 AM","firstname":"Herbert James","otherdatedate":"20/05/1950
>   12:00:00 AM","location":"Building
>   J","surname":"Brown","type":"Green"}]})

the salient bits of code are below.

```
<OperationContract> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="getBlend?surname={surname}&firstname={firstname}&othernames={othername}&yearfrom={yearfrom}&yearto={yearto}")>

Function GetBlend(ByVal surname As String, ByVal firstname As String, ByVal othername As String, ByVal yearfrom As String, ByVal yearto As String) As List(Of RestBlend)


Public Function GetBlend(ByVal surname As String, ByVal firstname As String,     ByVal othername As String, ByVal yearfrom As String, ByVal yearto As String) As    List(Of RestBlendDeceased) Implements IService.GetBlendDeceased
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim results As String = String.Empty
    Dim qrystr1 As String = String.Empty
    Dim qrystr2 As String = String.Empty

    Dim returndata As New List(Of RestBlendDeceased)

    myConn = New SqlConnection(DatabaseHelpers.conn)

'query to retrieve data 

        Do While myReader.Read()
            Dim aRestBlend As New RestBlend

            aRestBlendDeceased.age = myReader("age").ToString
            aRestBlendDeceased.firstname = myReader("field1").ToString
            aRestBlendDeceased.surname = myReader("field2").ToString
            aRestBlendDeceased.dateofsomething = myReader("field3").ToString
            aRestBlendDeceased.otherdate = myReader("field4").ToString
            aRestBlendDeceased.location = myReader("location").ToString
            aRestBlendDeceased.type = myReader("type").ToString
            returndata.Add(aRestBlend)
        Loop

        myReader.Close()
        myConn.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If myConn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then myConn.Close()
    End Try

    Return returndata

End Function
```

I have many other json contracts working on this service but this one needs to be different. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the client have a good reason for wanting it in non-JSON format?  You could always just return it as a simple string.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim commented, it's not usual to get a non-json format, it would be very easy to get the json and format on client but...

Anyway, you can get the serialized json and put in a formated string, something like this:

```
Dim jsonStr As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returndata)
Return String.Contact("jsoncallback(", jsonStr , ")")
```

Hope it helps